# Получение текущего значения из dropdown и отправка его на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax, golang

Я новичок в AJAX и пытаюсь изучать базовые вызовы через AJAX и jQuery. У меня есть простой выпадающий список стран, в котором я хочу выбрать конкретную страну и отправить ее значение на сервер, где он будет обрабатывать, какая страна была выбрана, и выдавать определенный результат.
Выпадающий список  заполняю из БД, хотелось бы узнать как получить текущее значение списка, в моём коде отправляется только первое значение на сервер.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
        {{ range .}}
        <button type="submit" id="ajax_btn" class="dropdown-item"  value="Submit">{{ .Title}}</button>

        {{ end }}
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#ajax_btn").on('click',function () {
       button = this.value;
       var el = document.getElementById("ajax_btn").innerHTML;
       if (button == "Submit"){
           $.ajax({
               url:"receive",
               type: "POST",
               data: {button: el},
               success: function(results) {
                   console.log(results)
                   $('#response').html(results);
               }
           });
       }

   });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в AJAX, а в том, что Вы используете селектор по ID `$("#ajax_btn")`. Так как у валидного HTML может быть только один экземпляр ID на странице — jQuery возвращает первое совпадение. Соответственно событие вешается только на первую кнопку. Используйте селектор по классу (: